# Как создать и взаимодействовать с приватным чатом через pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как взаимодействовать с приватным чатом в тг?

```
@app.on_message()
async def get_data(c: Client, m: types.Message):
    if m.from_user.id == id:
        print(m)
```

А больше кода нет, да и этот никак не реагирует на приватный чат

В документации видел что-то про EncryptedChat, но как с ним работать не пойму

Если кто-то спросит зачем, отвечаю: Надо запретить копирование/пересылку/сохранение контента из телеграмм бота (пока что я придумал только через приватный чат, но вот как с ним взаимодействовать честно говоря не знаю). Может кто-то знает как реализовать такое на pyrogram или может даже aiogram?